# Using define in a conditional expression in Scheme

Tags: naming, conditions, scheme

In Scheme, the general form of a *procedure definition* is:

> (define (<*name*> <*parameters*>) <*body*>)

where <*body*> accepts a sequence of expressions, allowing this kind of procedure definitions:

```
> (define (f) 1 2 3)
> (f)
3
```

Likewise, the general form of a *conditional expression* is:

> (cond (<*predicate*> <*consequent*>) (<*predicate*> <*consequent*>) … (<*predicate*> <*consequent*>))

where <*consequent*> in each clause accepts a sequence of expressions, allowing this kind of conditional expressions:

```
> (cond (#t 1 2 3))
3
```

**But why can’t I use `define` in a clause’s consequent of a conditional expression like in the body of a procedure definition?**

Compare:

```
> (define (f) (define x 1) (define y 1) (define z 1) (+ x y z))
> (f)
3
```

with:

```
> (cond (#t (define x 1) (define y 1) (define z 1) (+ x y z)))
ERROR on line 1: unexpected define: (define x 1)
```

*Note.* — I am using the Chibi-Scheme 0.8.0 implementation on MacOS 10.15.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`define` can only be used at either the top-level, or at the beginning of a `body`. It cannot be used in other places where expressions can be used. [Here](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%25_sec_5.2) is the relevant quote from R5RS:

> Definitions are valid in some, but not all, contexts where expressions
>   are allowed. They are valid only at the top level of a <program> and
>   at the beginning of a <body>.

The cases of a `cond` are not `body`s, and so you cannot put a `define` there.